# Pandas: impose datetime timeline from one dataframe into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have these 2 dataframes:

main_df:

```
    value    feed_id                created_at  
0     0.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:38:18-05:00   
1     1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:39:26-05:00   
2     1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:40:33-05:00   
3     1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:41:41-05:00   
4     1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:42:49-05:00   
5     1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:43:56-05:00
```

aux_df:

```
       value    feed_id                created_at
0  20.298492  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:35:33-05:00
1  20.315002  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:36:34-05:00
2  20.315002  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:37:36-05:00
3  20.359650  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:38:36-05:00
4  20.359650  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:39:37-05:00
5  20.383179  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:40:38-05:00
6  20.383179  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:41:38-05:00
7  20.449524  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:42:39-05:00
8  20.449524  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:43:40-05:00
9  20.521912  1009408.0 2019-03-06 07:44:41-05:00
```

I want the following (final_df) on this condition: I want the "timeline" described in the 'created_at' column from aux_df, to be completely merged into main_df, regardless if it has common or not common values in both columns. For the common ones I take the whole timestamp and ignore the part that's in seconds (notice how **all the values are aligned by the same date, hour and minutes but not seconds**).

```
       value    feed_id                created_at
0        nan        nan 2019-03-06 07:35:33-05:00
1        nan        nan 2019-03-06 07:36:34-05:00
2        nan        nan 2019-03-06 07:37:36-05:00
3        0.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:38:36-05:00
4        1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:39:37-05:00
5        1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:40:38-05:00
6        1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:41:38-05:00
7        1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:42:39-05:00
8        1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:43:40-05:00
9        nan        nan 2019-03-06 07:44:41-05:00
```

The strategy I tried but didn't succeed:

1. Create a new column on both dataframes named 'created_at_2' using
   'round' by the minute on each timestamp, so I could just discard the
   seconds part on the timestamp before I do the merge.
2. Use merge.

   main_df['created_at_2'] = main_df.created_at.dt.round('min')
   aux_df['created_at_2'] = aux_df.created_at.dt.round('min')
   final_df = pd.merge(main_df, aux_df, on=['created_at_2'], how='inner')

But this method is not robust, as indicated in this example. When you round timestamps like 2019-03-06 07:40:33-05:00, you'll get 41 minutes instead of 40. And I need a continuous by-the-minute column.

I could just re-format the timestamp timeline using this:

```
main_df.created_at.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
aux_df.created_at.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
final_df = pd.merge(main_df, aux_df, on=['created_at_2'], how='inner')
```

But not sure if this method is robust and I'd still need to index the values that are not common from the 'created_at' column. So, is there a more proper way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), but last row is different:

```
main_df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(main_df['created_at'])
aux_df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(aux_df['created_at'])

df = pd.merge_asof(aux_df[['created_at']], main_df, on=['created_at'])
print (df)
                 created_at  value    feed_id
0 2019-03-06 07:35:33-05:00    NaN        NaN
1 2019-03-06 07:36:34-05:00    NaN        NaN
2 2019-03-06 07:37:36-05:00    NaN        NaN
3 2019-03-06 07:38:36-05:00    0.0  1010077.0
4 2019-03-06 07:39:37-05:00    1.0  1010077.0
5 2019-03-06 07:40:38-05:00    1.0  1010077.0
6 2019-03-06 07:41:38-05:00    1.0  1010077.0
7 2019-03-06 07:42:39-05:00    1.0  1010077.0
8 2019-03-06 07:43:40-05:00    1.0  1010077.0
9 2019-03-06 07:44:41-05:00    1.0  1010077.0
```

Another is use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) instead `round`:

```
main_df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(main_df['created_at'])
aux_df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(aux_df['created_at'])
main_df['created_at_2'] = main_df.created_at.dt.floor('min') 
aux_df['created_at_2'] = aux_df.created_at.dt.floor('min') 

df = pd.merge(aux_df[['created_at_2']], main_df, on=['created_at_2'], how='left')
print (df)
               created_at_2  value    feed_id                created_at
0 2019-03-06 07:35:00-05:00    NaN        NaN                       NaT
1 2019-03-06 07:36:00-05:00    NaN        NaN                       NaT
2 2019-03-06 07:37:00-05:00    NaN        NaN                       NaT
3 2019-03-06 07:38:00-05:00    0.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:38:18-05:00
4 2019-03-06 07:39:00-05:00    1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:39:26-05:00
5 2019-03-06 07:40:00-05:00    1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:40:33-05:00
6 2019-03-06 07:41:00-05:00    1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:41:41-05:00
7 2019-03-06 07:42:00-05:00    1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:42:49-05:00
8 2019-03-06 07:43:00-05:00    1.0  1010077.0 2019-03-06 07:43:56-05:00
9 2019-03-06 07:44:00-05:00    NaN        NaN                       NaT
```

Comment: I came up with another solution that I can't post as an answer properly because I didn't enable that option. But yours worked as well, at the end I stayed with mine. Let me describe a bit what I did here: 

The re-formatted timestamp for main_df was used as index, then I used .loc indexing these values: aux_df.created_at_2.values.tolist() and after that I applied merge. 

Thanks for the additional approaches! :)